# Finite Fields and Discrete Log Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields

> The finite field $\mathbb F_{p^p}$, for a prime $p$, can be described as $\mathbb F_p[x]/(x^p−x−1)$. Let $G=\mathbb F_{p^p}^\times/\mathbb F_{p}^\times$. Estimate the cost of obtaining the discrete
>   log base $x$ of an arbitrary element of G using the elements of $G$ with a
>   representative of the form $x − a$, $a ∈ \mathbb F_p$ as factor base.

Can some one please explain this in detail to me?

So far i have found the elements in **F**p*, (all the elements from 1,2,,,,p-1, for some value of p)

However i dont understand what to do next in terms of trying to find the cost of obtaining the discrete log base x? Also what is it meaning by representative of the form  x − a, a ∈ **F**p as factor base?

Comment: Looks like you are supposed to use index calculus. Finding the base logs of the (cosets of the) linear polynomials $x-a$ should not be too difficult. Don't know what special considerations apply in the estimation. Basically use of index calculus amounts to finding a power $x^t$ such that when you multiply the element of interest by $x^t$, you  get a polynomial that splits into linear factors over $\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: How do I determine which polynomials are in the field **F**p^p?

Comment: Sorry im just super confused how to answer this question, i really have no idea where to begin